# How to download attachments from SF(salesforce) webservice using Spring Integration (WebService Inbound Adapter)

Tags: spring-integration

I have a situation where I have to pull the attachments from sfdc webservice and put it into some other ftp location. I need a suggestion, if anybody faced this situation please share approach.

please help to develop this interface

thanks in advance
Samba

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear, so that would be better to share more info on the matter and maybe some code, config.

Anyway, Spring Integration WS module is fully based on the Spring WS projects and deals exactly with the `WebServiceMessage` abstraction.

Which you can cast to the `MimeMessage` in case of `MTOM` enabled on request/response.

And that one `getAttachments()` method.

In case of Inbound Gateway you can use `extractPayload = false`  option and receive a full `WebServiceMessage` as a `payload` in downstream flow.

When you send request to the external service and receive response with an attachments, you should take a look into custom `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` extension, where you can populate your attachments into headers in the `extractUserDefinedHeaders` overridden method.

Comment: Thanks for you Answer, sorry if my question is not clear.                               Actually got a requirement for new integration component .......(sales-force) team providing a webservice , which is capable for sending files as attachments. my interface should able to consume that service to get those attachments and  drop them  into some other ftp location

Comment: Well, that doesn't help anyway. It is your business and it isn't clear for us. You have to share some generic info about your task and some PoC. Anyway that would be great to hear from you back about my answer. Maybe there is no more reason already to continue our discussion because there are a lot of other work to do...